# SQL trigger delete a manager only if a condition is true

Tags: mysql, triggers, schema

I have three tables, Manager, Manages and Department. A department can have many managers and a manager can have many departments so Manages is a many to many relationship. Every department needs at least one manager

The schemas are below
Manager(mid)
Manages(mid, did)
Department(did)

How do I write a SQL trigger that deleted a Manager only if it is not the only manager assigned to any department?

Comment: don't need a trigger use foreign keys

Comment: I thought a foreign key for Manages means that I won't be able to delete any manager that is assigned to a department. I want to delete a manager from a department except those managers that are the only manager in a department

Comment: The trigger should prevent the last manager from being deleted.

Comment: Any idea how to write that?